# Adding image to div, getting $ is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an image to all lightboxes.
But I am getting the error $ is not a function.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-inner").append("<img style='position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;' src='http://juvama.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/stempel1.png'>");
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you added reference to jQuery library?

Comment: If you have jquery, it should work just fine. Or you might have used `noConflict` mode, which you can use it with `jQuery` instead of `$`..

Comment: If you replace `$` with `jQuery`, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

try to add jQuery to head

```
<head>
    <script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```